# How to Create Planned vs Actual Chart in BIRT

Tags: birt

I am trying to plot both the cummulated projected and cummulated actual number of hours worked on a project. I am trying to plot these two lines as two different series on a line graph.

I would like the planned line to show the accumulated hours planned, by month, for every month since the project started until the project ends.

I would like the actual line to show the accumulated actual hours spent on the project, by month, for every month from when the projected started to the current month, and then stop (not hold at the current value).

I have data/queries set up this way, but when I try to plot the two series, the lines stop at the current month.

For examlpe, I have a project that goes from January 2013 to December 2013. I have the cummulated planned hours for each month from January to December 2013 as (150, 300, 600, 900, 1200, 1500, 1950, 2350, 2650, 2950, 3250, 3400). So far my actual hours spent for January through July are (100, 250, 400, 750, 1050, 1350, 1750).

My chart right now only shows both series through July 2013. I would like series 1 (planned) to show me values for all 12 months. I would like series 2 (actual) to show me values through July, and then stop. I can add data to the actual column and set it equal to the prior month if it there is no value, but this gives an unsightly and potentially confusing flat line for actuals for the remaining months of the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your lines stop at the current month it is probably due to queries. For example this [chart](http://www.visioneo.org/chart) acts as your need.

How do you join actual & budget data, In SQL queries or a joined dataset? There is probably an "inner join" that should be an "outer join".

Comment: We have been able to use our data to recreate the chart as you show it, with one series as a line and one series as a column. What we would like to do is have both series' be lines.

Comment: Our data is in one table. There are three fields. One field is the year/month combo (201301, 201302,...), one field is the accumulated planned spending, and one field is the accumulated actual spending. So for the rows where the year/month has passed (..., 201306, 201307) we have data in both the accumulated planned and accumulated actual fields. But for future months (201308, 201309, ...) the accumulated actual field is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not sure what the problem was. Started over from scratch and this time the chart worked. Didn't change the query or anything. Must have had something else set that I didn't know about.